# How to exit with SIGSEGV instead of SIGABRT?

Tags: c, gdb, signals, stack-overflow

I am learning how to cause *Buffer Overflows* with this code.
Then I am running this with **GDB** and when I input bad data that causes the smashing of the Stack I exit with 
`Program received signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
0x00007ffff7a4af79 in __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6)
    at ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:56
56  ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c: No such file or directory.`
but the the both guide I am reading exits with `SIGSEGV` or `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` with the reason (in the last case) `KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS` and the address that actually are the bad input.

How do I exit with those Signals? Is it my system that is configured to work that way?

I am running on `Ubuntu 14.04 LTS Trusty`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int test(char *test) {
    char buf[10];
    strcpy(buf, test);

    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    test(argv[1]);
    printf("After test: %s\n", argv[1]);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: works for me; copy/pasted your program, running in gdb gives me: "Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault." (Ubuntu 14.10)

Comment: @nlu Weird. In mines not. Not in gdb nor at terminal. I don't know if this is useful but I am running on a Thinkpad T440 and in their BIOS there is some configs about preventing Buffer Overflows. Does it impact in something?

Comment: See the answer of @Arjun Sreedharan

Answer (score 2):

Your compiler seems to implement *stack smashing protection* to protect from buffer overflow. Compile with `-fno-stack-protector` flag.

Answer (score 0):

You need to disable the -fstack-protector when compiling your c file.

Compile like so:

```
gcc yourFileName.c -o yourFileName -fno-stack-protector
```

In your case it would be `gcc raise.c -o raise -fno-stack-protector`
then run with GDB using `gdb ./raise`. You can then overflow the buffer right after by running something like

```
run $(python –c “print(‘F’*32)”)
```

which will overflow your `char buf[10];` by placing 32 'F' characters into `buf[10]`. This will cause the SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault to display.